# Is there a way to identify bolded (<b></b>) with Celerity

Tags: screen-scraping, celerity

I'm using celerity to do some screen scraping and have come across the need to identify text elements that are in bold.  Celerity offers a strong method but does not offer a bold method. Has anyone figured out a clever way around this with Celerity or other tool.  I tried using:

```
browser.html.gsub!(<b>,<strong>)
browser.html.gsub!(</b>,</strong>)
```

I though I could replace the bold elements with strong elements and then simply use celerity's strong method, but this didn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems strange that b is missing but you can try:

```
browser.elements_by_xpath('//b').each do |b|
    puts "#{b} is a bold tag"
end
```